# Calculate your Icy Tower Score

Tags: code-golf

Do you know [Icy Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icy_Tower) ? Here is a [gameplay example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmyRdsuXdd0) of what i'm talking about

The game concept is simple : you play as Harold the Homeboy, and your goal is to jump from floors to floors to go as high as possible without falling and getting off-screen ( the camera goes higher following you or at a speed that gets faster over time, and does not go down ).

If you get off-screen ( fell or camera was too fast for you to keep up ), it's game over, and then you get a score.

Your task is to write a program/function/whatever that calculates the score based on a input.

#### How to calculate the score :

The formula is simple : \$Score = 10 * LastFloor +  Sum(ValidComboList.TotalFloorJumped^2)\$

#### What is a valid combo ?

You have to jump from floors to floors to go as high as possible. Sometimes, you will the to the floor \$F+1\$

But sometimes, if you go fast enough ( faster = higher jumps ), you will do a multi-floor jump, and skip some floors between. A combo is a sequence of multi-floors jump. To be considered as a multi-floor jump, you need to skip at least 1 floor, meaning you need to get to the floor \$F+x\$ where \$x >= 2\$

See that you always jump to \$x >= 2\$, jumps to lower floors with floors skipped between are not considered valid

A combo ends when :

- You jump to the floor \$F+x\$ where \$(x < 0) | (x == 1)\$
- You wait more than about 3 seconds on the same floor ( in the gameplay video, you can see on the left a "timing bar", and the combo ends if it gets empty )
- You get off-screen ( falling or not jumping fast enough )

In this challenge, to simplify a bit, we will consider that, when the input indicates a "jump to the same floor \$F+0\$" means that the 3 second timeout is passed, so the two rules will be simplified in one :

"You jump to the floor \$F+x\$ where \$x<2\$

A valid combo ( a combo that will be used for the score calculation ) :

- The number of multi-floor jumps \$N >= 2\$
- The combo MUST NOT end with going off-screen. If you go off-screen, the combo is invalid and won't included in the score. Said in another way : The combo must be followed by a jump to another floor or by waiting about 3 seconds.

In this challenge, since we consider that jumping to the same floor is waiting 3 seconds, the rules to make a valid combo is "You must jump to another floor"

Since you need at least 2 multi-floor jumps to make a combo, the number of total floor jumped is higher than 4

#### The input

The input will be a "list" of integers ( or STDIN input ) which represents the sequence of floor jumped on. For example, the start to the video linked previously in the post will look like :

```
[5 4 5 10 12 15 17 18 19 20 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 34 35 36 37 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 43 48 45 46 50 55 54]
```

for the first floors. The start floor is ommited. This input end on floor 54 meaning he went off-screen just after that, without getting to another floor, so there's the game over ( this was not the case in the video since he went to the floor 232, so the array accurately representing the sequence would end with 232 at the end )

Here, with this input, you must output \$829\$, because :

\$Score = 10 * 54 + 12^2 + 8^2 + 9^2\$ Because the last floor Harold was on is the floor number 54, and he made 3 valid combos :

- First combo of 4 multi-floor jumps with a total of  12 floors jumped in that combo
- Second combo of 2 multi-floor jumps with a total of 8 floors jumped in that combo
- The last combo of 2 multi-floor jumps with a total of 9 floors jumped in that combo

### Test cases :

`[] => Undefined Behavior`

`[5]` => \$50\$

`[4 0 5 6 8 10 10]` => \$10*10 + 4^2 = 116\$ **Correction applied**

`[4 0 5 6 6 6 6 8 10 10]` => \$10*10 + 4^2 = 116\$ ( Here, Harold just waited 9 seconds. No combo to validate, but still a legitimate input ) **Correction applied**

`[5 7 10 10 11 9 14 17 15 16]` => \$10*16 + 10^2 + 8^2 = 324\$

`[5 4 5 10 12 15 17 18 19 20 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 34 35 36 37 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 43 48 45 46 50 55 54]` => \$10 * 54 + 12^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 = 829\$

`[5 4 5 10 12 15 17 18 19 20 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 34 35 36 37 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 43 48 45 46 50 55 56]` => \$10 * 54 + 12^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 = 849\$

`[5 4 5 10 12 15 17 18 19 20 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 34 35 36 37 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 43 48 45 46 50 55 55]` => \$10 * 55 + 12^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 = 839\$ ( harold waited 3 seconds to validate the combo )

`[5 4 5 10 12 15 17 18 19 20 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 34 35 36 37 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 43 48 45 46 50 55]` => \$10 * 55 + 12^2 + 8^2 = 758\$ ( because harold went off-screen without confirming the combo)

If you want, you can condsider that the input always starts with zero ( since the game start at floor 0 ), if this is the case, say it in your answer

### Rules :

- Input and output in [any convenient way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/72535)
- Full program, or function, or lambda, or macro are acceptable
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/72535) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lower number of bytes are better

Edit : Correction applied on some test cases

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 24 bytes

*-1 byte from @kamil <3, -3 from @Shaggy :o. These guys are genius*

```
ä- ô>2n)¯J lÉ mx x²+A*Uo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY07DsJADAWv4hbYSMT2EtIgpU2XggqloEX8CopcgXukR0I5QfZgy6SnGMseP9mX8/OVcxoLSdNB76v508o1veU2yDB/N836@Mj5FIN4EGq5BYWlr2APdRDFqwExZad4xRveSsAb3nZQ/ZnJG3kn79xxZl@@so@4SB@9l6L7AQ) or [Test it all](https://tio.run/##vY87CsJQEEV7V3FbNULeZ/JpBFtLwSqksBV/hYVbcB/2grgCs7B4kjQK1pLcx8yd4Z37tpvTuW2b20zNc@4P49d9qV1z1f6iy@sxXUzWx7atRlUqq7szikqZCrmU/8sbvs@JKR86OadSLsphmFw2jBPFpDtdijzq6hwVqEzk8X1ArHlmHt/jB/zgEH7ADxnKf/TsB/Yj@5F7In3sqMwNz6gtksV4hPU5fZ@PlLyjJAB88NCBwwYNGRAcMFC@6wIeOGjAYIGCBEiW/Yljf@HUo1qz/eoN)

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 28 bytes, prev approach

*Naive Way*.

**Important** Input should start with 0 to work correctly (in some cases)

```
o *A+UóÈÄ¦Y©Y>XÃl>2 ®ä- xÃxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xCgJBDEWvklpnwU1mXG0WPIKF4CIWtiK4hcX2a@FBRLCx8QaTg41ve4sXkpdPcj71t1KuMtvMd/71h9/zq8vvrt37eGlV8seflQw@Dn0phxQkBqHWC1CY@gZWsA6ieDUgpuwUr3jDWw14w9sSmj8zeSMfyUfuROY4fWWfcIk@xaNU2x8) or [Test it all](https://tio.run/##vY@9isJQEIV7n@LUboTcn8lPI/gKgqBICttll7WwSK@FDyKCjc2@Qe6DZb@YZgVrSc5l5sxwv3M/d/tD3/9ouvhYpd90Tqfuuulum/k6Hb/mXt09XWZq07Hd9/12ss1lzXBGUalQJZfzP3nj939iKsdOzqmWi3IYJleM40wxG06XI4@GukQVqjN5fB8Qa56Zx/f4AT84hB/wQ4HKFz37gf3IfuSeSB8HKnPDM2qLZDEeYY@c/pGPlLyjJgB88NCBwwYNGRAcMFCe6woeOGjAYIGCBEhWvIljb@E0k0az7@Uf)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=5C0g9D4ybimvSiBrX8o8MsNteCB4sitBKlVv&input=WzUgNCA1IDEwIDEyIDE1IDE3IDE4IDE5IDIwIDIzIDI0IDI1IDI4IDI5IDMwIDMxIDM0IDM1IDM2IDM3IDM0IDM1IDM2IDM3IDM4IDM5IDQwIDQzIDQ4IDQ1IDQ2IDUwIDU1XQ==)

Comment: [Quick 3 byte saving](https://tio.run/##bY07DsJADAWv4hbYSMT2EtIgpU2XggqloEX8CopcgXukR0I5QfZgy6SnGMseP9mX8/OVcxoLSdNB76v508o1veU2yDB/N836@Mj5FIN4EGq5BYWlr2APdRDFqwExZad4xRveSsAb3nZQ/ZnJG3kn79xxZl@@so@4SB@9l6L7AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 72 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(v=>(v-p>1?r=c++?r:p:t+=(c>1)*(c=0,p-r)**2,p=v),t=c=p=0)&&t+p*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZLLboMwEEX3/QpWkQ2XxE8wkUyk/kNXVRcWj5YqBYsgfp@6DVk0VdUl8iwsz7lzbMnvbnaXauz8lPZD3SytXZwt3f7DeTLbksypL/lptFWSnMajP06JJVXJaUwqy@DTkcaxgLczxWQr6y2ju92U@JizpRr6y3Bu9ufhlbTk@YXS6HCInvq6abu@qaPH5s3N3TA@3IF6JTW77ygwaGQw4CzUynGe/QVe17@4Rn5FwDkKcAUeDjR4tmakUL8zKii@IuIbDYHgKSAYhIRQEBrCQBSQDJJDKkgNmUHmP/cGsoBiUBLKQIW5GXS4voZWq96IYgv97fVGbaK//QMjN9Cv7lyb5RM)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                  // a[] = input array
  a.map(v => (        // for each value v in a[]:
      v - p > 1 ?     //   if the difference with the previous floor is greater than 1:
        r = c++ ?     //     increment the combo counter c; if c was not equal to 0:
          r           //       leave r unchanged
        :             //     else:
          p           //       set r (reference floor) to the previous floor p
      :               //   else:
        t +=          //     update t only ...
          (c > 1) * ( //     ... if we have a multi-floor jump combo of at least 2 jumps
            c = 0,    //     reset c to 0
            p - r     //     compute the total number of floors jumped in the combo
          ) ** 2,     //     square it and add it to t
      p = v           //   set the previous value p to v
    ),                //
    t = c = p = 0     //   start with t = c = p = 0
  ) &&                // end of map()
  t + p * 10          // add the final floor multiplied by 10 to t
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 54 bytes

```
[:((10*{:)+1#.[:}:]((2<#)*[:*:{:-{.);.1~1,2>2-~/\])0&,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZHBTsMwDIbve4pfTGJNaUsc22lqGBckTpy4lp3QpokLD1CxVy9Z28skzlUSKbE/@XOS7/Gu2Z2wN@xQwcPyqhu8fry/jb0VBflyMPdA26a3XzsURXjeurK30garh8Y9NXShKryE@vL4eXD@vhrd5vh1/oF67HFCZTqfOcgUULQgP01CBxJQDigozhxRnDjJnSgi0kz/n5zHDZJCt3gkr2siTOWzJHMdgkdg5GaCIiRkmj2YwAJWcAS3t/sE7iAewpAEyXXj9XKqUFmUsp5yeaXE6ymXD2w1raTcjH8)

May add explanation later.  For now here's an ungolfed and a parsed version:

#### ungolfed

```
[: ((10 * {:) + 1 #. [: }: ] ((2 < #) * [: *: {: - {.);.1~ 1 , 2 > 2 -~/\ ]) 0&,
```

#### parsed

```
┌──┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│[:│┌─────────┬─┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│┌─┬─┬─┐│
│  ││┌──┬─┬──┐│+│┌─┬──┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│││0│&│,││
│  │││10│*│{:││ ││1│#.│┌──┬──┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│││└─┴─┴─┘│
│  ││└──┴─┴──┘│ ││ │  ││[:│}:│┌─┬────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││]│┌────────────────────────────────────┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─────────────────────────┐│││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││┌─────────────────────────────┬──┬─┐│~│││1│,│┌─┬─┬───────────────────┐││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │││┌───────┬─┬─────────────────┐│;.│1││ │││ │ ││2│>│┌─┬─────────────┬─┐│││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││││┌─┬─┬─┐│*│┌──┬──┬─────────┐││  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││2│┌─────────┬─┐│]││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │││││2│<│#││ ││[:│*:│┌──┬─┬──┐│││  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││ ││┌─────┬─┐│\││ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││││└─┴─┴─┘│ ││  │  ││{:│-│{.││││  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││ │││┌─┬─┐│/││ ││ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││││       │ ││  │  │└──┴─┴──┘│││  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││ ││││-│~││ ││ ││ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││││       │ │└──┴──┴─────────┘││  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││ │││└─┴─┘│ ││ ││ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │││└───────┴─┴─────────────────┘│  │ ││ │││ │ ││ │ ││ ││└─────┴─┘│ ││ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ ││└─────────────────────────────┴──┴─┘│ │││ │ ││ │ ││ │└─────────┴─┘│ ││││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │└────────────────────────────────────┴─┘││ │ ││ │ │└─┴─────────────┴─┘│││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │                                        ││ │ │└─┴─┴───────────────────┘││││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  ││ │                                        │└─┴─┴─────────────────────────┘│││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  ││  │  │└─┴────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘││││       │
│  ││         │ ││ │  │└──┴──┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│││       │
│  ││         │ │└─┴──┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘││       │
│  │└─────────┴─┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│       │
└──┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>202</s> <s>190</s> <s>188</s> <s>187</s> <s>184</s> <s>181</s> <s>177</s> <s>170</s> <s>166</s> 164 bytes

```cpp
int f(int*a,int l){int r=a[l-1]*10,i=0,j,k,s;for(;i<l;i++)for(j=l;s=j-->i;s&&j-i>1&&~j+l?r+=(a[i]-a[j])*(a[i]-a[i=j]),j=l:0)for(k=j;k-i;)s*=a[k--]-a[k]>1;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZFba4MwGIav568IG5Rq34A5aHWpjnY/Q7wQa0vU2uLhqnR/3SUdZRR2Pcjh/eDJ9ySkvFzosSznWXcjOSzN6hWwuXWvduuTImspyz3mQyc@ajQY1OHcL5XetEqvVq4t6qRVQ1JTmmo1LBY11SlbLL7qVfvRr5JlkemcFlmdu94j68RUMOfe/XuHJqlVQ7VyB88oG0ot1OQpU301Tn1HenWb33RXttO@Iht9Hsa@Kk6pMw26OxLSFadquBRlRYZxrxzHXv5U6G7pkqvzYqttlpOrjwDSTPMcxsFMWINFYDG4Dy7AJXgAHoHHED4Eg5AQAUQIsX7OEUQM6UMKyAjS9A0RmP4BAnlTP87dfzkfws@HcH3XmcEQg8m705hDC5bnaSSbjfnvLYgIXZtfSWKmCRGP7VZ1@/YJ3Rk0eEbXQfQn@gnC2DMquPxFb/M3)

Input must begin with 0.

-11 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Comment: Updated, @ceilingcat